# How to find the expected number of days?

Tags: probability, expectation

Here is the problem that I am trying to solve:

A hospital handles 20 births a day. Ten percent require a special fetal monitor. Find the expected number of days out of the year when the hospital will need at least two monitors.

Any help would be great.

Comment: According to your question, the hospital has exactly $2$ monitors **every single day**. So the expected number of days with at least $2$ monitors is $365$. No probability computation involved here.

Comment: Hint:  use indicator variables.  Let $X_i$ be $1$ if day $i$ requires at least two monitors, $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Note:  I am assuming that what you meant was that the probability that a newborn required the monitor is $.1$ independent of all the other newborns.  Thus there is a binomial distribution here and there is some chance than none or just one of the newborns born on some given day require the device.

Comment: @barakmanos: It would be a much better interpretation of the problem that each of the 20 births _independently_ needs a monitor with probability $1/10$.

Comment: Do we assume that the number of births per day is constantly 20, or something like if $X$ is the number of births, then $X\sim\text{Pois}(20)$?

Comment: is the 20 births a day fixed, or is that an average - an average would make most sense - therefore the model is that the number of monitors needed is poisson with parameter 0.1 x 20 = 2

Comment: Is this just a homework-like problem? Then okay. But if you're doing a calculation for a real hospital, then in the ten percent of births requiring a monitor, for **how long** is that monitor needed on average? For example, if a baby needs monitoring for two weeks after birth, he'll tie up one monitor for two weeks, and there'll be lots and lots of days when at least two monitors will be needed. But if a baby only needs monitoring for two hours after birth, there'll be hardly any days when two monitors will be needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As also pointed out in the comments, we are assuming that the number of samples is so large such that the probability that each newborn needs the device is $0.1$, independent of others.

Assume any day. The probability that no newborn needs the monitor is $0.9^{20}$. Similarly, the probability that exactly one monitor is needed is $(20)(0.1)0.9^{19}$. Hence the probability that at least two monitors are needed becomes $p=1-0.9^{20}-(20)(0.1)0.9^{19}=0.6083$.

To calculate the expectation, notice that the number of days that the desired event happen follows a binomial $n=365,p$ distribution. 
Therefore, the expected number of days that this event happens is $365p=222.3$ days.

Answer (score 2):

The answer made by msm is good. Just with a small mistake: the probability that exactly one monitor needed should be $(20)(0.1)0.9^{19}$. Thus, the probability that at least two monitors are needed becomes $p=1−(0.9)^{20}−(20)(0.1)(0.9)^{19}=0.6083$.

Taking $365.25$ days to be the expected number of days a year, the expected number of days out of a year that the hospital needs at least two monitors is $365.25 p = 222$ days.

Comment: Yes! that was a mistake (+1)

Answer (score 1):

You need the probability of needing at least two monitors on a given day. Once you have that, multiply by the number of days in a year to get the answer.

To get the probability of needing at least two or more monitors, think about it like this: Each birth is like a weighted coin flip that comes up "heads" (i.e. patient needs a monitor) only 10% of the time. So you need the probability of having two or more "heads" out of 20 biased coin flips under these conditions. The binomial distribution will come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

if the 20 births a day is an average, then you could use poisson with $ \lambda = 20 \times 0.1 = 2$

$P(0) = e^{-\lambda} =$
$P(1) = \lambda e^{-\lambda}$

$P(>=2) = 1 - P(0) - P(1) = 1 - .1353 - .2707 = .594

no of days per year = .594 x 365.25  = 217